# Removable glue for LEGO models

Tags: glue

I want to glue my 4-year-old's LEGO bricks, but I want to be able to remove the glue when he is older. What is the best glue to use that is removable and okay to use on LEGO bricks?

Comment: Standard LEGO brick are probably *not* the right toy if you need to glue them.  I would look at LEGO Duplo bricks, which are specifically designed for younger kids.  Then you wouldn't have to glue them.

Comment: People, people, people. Respect the lady's question and try to answer it. It's not a question about the morality of gluing bricks together, nor the wisdom of a 4-year old having LEGO bricks (which, by the way, I personally am a huge proponent of, as long as we're going there). Let's assume she's a competent adult first, and go forward from there.

Answer (score 11):

Officially, LEGO Group doesn't recommend any adhesive on the toys. It can lead to corrosion or warping chemically, warping physically (the glue puts pressure on the pieces), and the removal of the adhesive also carries these risks. Plus, you'd be killing not only the the monetary value of the set, but the ability of those pieces to be active stimuli for creativity and motor skills.

The LEGO Movie clearly shows that using glue on the toys is what the villain does.

Answer (score 8):

I would say low temp hot glue. I have done this for several my son really wanted to "keep". I figure one day he will be able to take it apart but it saves it from dropping and such!

Comment: I'm voting this up because it is one of only two answers so far that actually answers the question.

Answer (score 7):

Your question doesn't explain why you want to glue the models for a 4 year old, so I'm going to go ahead and advocate that you don't glue and instead let your 4 year old build. 4 years old is a great time to be learning the fine motor skills, geometry, physics, colour and esthetics, not to mention creativity and storytelling. Gluing the models takes away their potential and makes Lego a blocky imitation of other toys.

Lego sells kits to 4 year olds (the Juniors line) that uses the exact same parts as the more complicated models in the other product lines. The main difference is build complexity; Lego Juniors use simple builds with few parts. With a bit of practice, your child should be able to handle the more complex construction of the other lines, which are typically set for ages 5 and up. That's only next year anyway.

Answer (score 3):

There are three factors you have to consider here:  the possible chocking hazard for your child, the possible toxicity of the glue to your child, and the degree of removability of the glue.

I don't think there exist a glue that is (1) completely secure (i.e. won't allow small parts to become chocking hazards), (2) safe to be handled and possibly ingested, and (3) completely removable for future play.

If I have to recommend a glue with the safety of your child in mind, I would recommend Super-glue.  Once dry, it is non-toxic and it won't melt the plastic in the bricks.  However, it is more-or-less permanent, which is important for safe playing time (and obviously doesn't meet condition 3 above).

I strongly recommend that you consider age-appropriate building toys, such as [LEGO Duplo](http://www.lego.com/en-us/duplo) bricks.  If you visit the [LEGO Store](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/), you can shop sets by age range to get an idea of what is available for your child.

Comment: Lego isn't exactly age-inappropriate for 4 year olds.

Comment: According to the LEGO group store, Duplo is the preferred toy for 3-4 year olds.

Comment: Duplo is suitable for 3-4 years old, but they also have the Juniors line which is for 4-7 years old. And it isn't a question of product safety; most 4 year olds are not putting the lego in their mouths. It's a question of age-appropriate themes and build complexity.

Comment: Why in the name of Sam Hill has this question become some kind of platform for child safety and anti-glueness?

Answer (score 2):

As Nick says, LEGO System is probably not quite the right toy for a 4 year old. LEGO Duplo or possibly the new LEGO Juniors range would be better. LEGO obviously caution about the small parts on almost all System sets.

However, if you're looking for a temporary glue for now, then I'd probably go with a water based glue such as PVA that you'll eventually be able to soak off.

Be aware though, that this will not create as secure a bond as a permanent glue, so I would certainly advise supervising the play in case smaller elements come off.

Comment: Actually, Elmer's *is* in fact a PVA-based glue.

Comment: Yes, I believe Glue-All is a PVA glue, but a number of their other products aren't (for example ProBond or Kragle I mean Krazy Glue)

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the difference between Lego Juniors is build complexity, and not such much difference in choking hazards.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 True, but they are [aimed at 4 year olds](http://www.lego.com/en-gb/juniors/about): "LEGO® Juniors is designed to give children **age 4-7** a great first experience with the LEGO® brick through iconic, fun and Easy to Build models."

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps try `hot glue` in some old test parts and after a few days, use rubbing alcohol to remove the joining power of the glue.

I use this method in foam planes and it separates the glue just fine.

Answer (score 0):

www.le-glue.com is perfect for what you need.

Comment: Hi lee and welcome to Bricks! You're the second person to recommend Le-Glue, however as you may have seen on the first one, we're looking for longer answers than you have provided - can you expand a little on your recommendation - have you used it yourself for example? Did it do as advertised? Also, if you're affiliated with the product in any way, please let us know.

Comment: Yes, please expand a bit. I'm not a LEGO gluer, but if people want to do it, and there is a purpose-made product for this and it works well, frankly this should be the accepted answer, and the highest-voted one.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is just to make the LEGO builds sturdier, and not straight unbreakable, I'd give a thought to the various food-based "glues", like sugar syrup (will probably become sticky to the touch as well) or [flour paste](https://www.ehow.com/how_8234873_make-glue-flour-water.html). Both have the benefits of being 100% food-safe and water-soluble, while still providing a bit of adhesive force.