# Temp Glue for LEGO

Tags: building, glue

We have a Train Station Set, but this built is so loose and comes apart so easily thus it is really hard to move/play/connect to other parts. Is there some product like temporary LEGO glue to stick things together in the span of months to a year, and can come of easily with some dissolvent?

P.S. I searched on StackExchange or Reddit, "DO NOT GLUE" does not fit my scenario.

EDIT: Add the picture. We assembled it, but the roof/pole/base falling apart easily simply when connecting with more rail tracks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.StackExchange.com! Can you give more details on the set you are referring to? Typical LEGO-branded sets do not come apart easily - I want to make sure you indeed have a LEGO set and not a clone-brand.

Comment: @PhilB.We have #60050, Train Station.

Comment: Interesting ... my son JUST built the same set a few days ago and we have no issues with it being loose - actually, I had to take the canopy apart and raise it by one plate just to let the caboose of my Holiday Train pass under it .... and the canopy didn't come off easily. Is there no way you can perhaps reinforce the part that comes loose with some extra LEGO pieces? Once you start gluing there is no going back ...

Comment: PS: The left destination overhead sign is not mounted correctly in your build :)

Comment: As per [my answer](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/4604/56) on the linked question, if you must go down the glued route, a water based glue such as PVA (for example Elmers Glue-all) will work and can then be soaked off later.

Comment: Track-side models often break off of train tracks when there is too much movement of the track. One of the easiest ways to prevent that, without glue, would be to put some plates under the track to build up the connection between the straight track pieces and the rest of the model. A baseplate works well for this, as long as your main model is well-connected to the baseplate. (baseplates are flexible, but with enough studs connected they hold well).