# How to glue a LEGO tree decoration in a way that's not permanent, to prevent accidental disassembling?

Tags: building, glue

I have a sweet LEGO Santa Claus and few other builds that would look cool as decorations on Christmas Tree. Sadly, it would probably break if I would try to hang it. It can stand all right but is not sturdy enough to hang, or to survive much handling, really.

So I want to glue it together. But I don't want it to stay glued. I want to be able to disassemble it when I no longer use it as an ornament that hangs on something. Is there any way to glue LEGO bricks and still be able to wash away the glue without damaging them when I want to?

Note: this question has nothing to do with the safety of 4 years old kids, like [this one](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/4603/9417), and strength of connection I'm asking about is way smaller (hanging on a tree vs kid potentially trying to take it apart).

Comment: As I said in [this answer](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/4604/56) I think the best option would be to use a water soluble glue (such as PVA, White Glue, Elmer's Glue All, etc.). This dries clear, but can be washed off with warm water and a soft brush.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removable glue for LEGO models](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4603/removable-glue-for-lego-models)

Comment: @chicks see my edit.

Comment: Thanks Molot.  That should help it be less confusing.  I'm going to tweak the title too.

Comment: @Molot - Still no answer? When you have them out next time could you please post a picture of them?  I have some ideas...

Comment: @JohnnyB it's long time to Xmass season. I hope I'll be tidying up my brick storage soon, then I'll post pictures.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the "clutch" power of bricks by sandwiching a piece of paper towel between each connection. Once the bricks are together, cut away the excess paper using a knife.

The effect of this is roughly the same as applying a weak glue. Your builds will not become impervious, but will hold up better to handling and hanging.

Comment: I'd like to note that this may only work for some bricks as there are cases where bricks without extra layer (like paper you mentioned) already tend to crack, thus loosing a clutch power.

Answer (score -2):

If you need it to be glued but not permanent, I'd try paper-mache paste. It'll wash out. I've never tried it, but I think it should work.